# Creating a multiple and where sql statement

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, between

I'm trying to create an sql statement which involves adding up a total of a cost field between two dates and where a customer id is to a certain value. My statement currently looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(COST) AS TotalCost
FROM   ORDERS
WHERE  ( DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '09/25/2015' )
       AND WHERE CUSTOMERID = '23'
```

However, I get an error when I run this which says:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at
>   line 1, column 98.

I know that it is a syntax error in my statement but I'm not sure how it should be written to prevent this from occurring

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the second WHERE

```
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '09/25/2015') AND CUSTOMERID='23'
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error instead

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and 'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported.

Comment: What type of field is CUSTOMERID? If an integer then your statement would be AND CUSTOMERID=23

Comment: It is an int and that has fixed that problem but now I have a different error saying the CUSTOMERID column doesn't exist even though it does

Comment: @NickKaraolis - This is not your personal debugging service.

Comment: @MartinSmith I never said it was, I was simply saying what happened after using his change of code

Comment: @NickKaraolis - This answers the question you originally asked about invalid syntax. Piling additional questions on without attempting to even think about yourself makes this a ["chameleon question"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22chameleon%20question%22) and you appear to be a ["help vampire"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire/258208#258208)

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry mum will take more care next time xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

This version should work; extra where clause, and I'm assuming your customerid is an integer, not a string.

```
SELECT  SUM(COST) AS TotalCost
FROM    ORDERS
WHERE   (
    DATE BETWEEN convert(datetime, '01/01/2012') AND convert(datetime, '09/25/2015')
)
AND     CUSTOMERID = 23
```